# MVC and Globalization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I have some code that when I step through changes the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`, but does not take the relevant string from .resx file, it just takes the one from the default culture.  Can anybody help, this is my code :

```
<map id="langs" name="langselect">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,18,11" alt="en-GB" onmouseover="tooltip.show('en-GB', 60);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onclick="setCulture('en-GB');" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="25,1,41,11" alt="fi-FI" onmouseover="tooltip.show('fi-FI', 48);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onclick="setCulture('fi-FI');"  />
        </map>

function setCulture(culture) {

    $.post('/Gameplan/MainGP/SetCulture', { culture: culture }, function (result) {

    });

}

public void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

    }
```

EDIT : I have added the following code, but I still have the same issue :

```
public void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        Session["Culture"] = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());
    }

protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: That's almost exactly how mine works - are your resource files the right ones (I know that seems a stupid question but simple mistakes are often the hardest to spot)

Comment: I also have this in the `web.config` `system.web` section `<globalization uiCulture="auto" />` but that's because I pick up the preferred language from the browser - shouldn't make a difference to you I don't think.

Comment: I can now get this to work using the code above, but only after doing a page refresh. I really need the language to change on clicking the flag image in my code above, rather than having to click refresh in the browser.

Comment: Also, won't calling Application_AcquireRequestState apply this to all sessions when you want to apply it to individual sessions?

Comment: You do need a page refresh - the text won't change (in a non dynamic part of your page) with an ajax post. You could redirecttoaction in your controller and show the page again. It only affects the individual session, not everyone.

Comment: RedirectToAction didn't refresh the page, do you have a code example for refreshing the page?

Comment: What is it that you want to change - Do you want to change the language for the whole application (for this user) or only change a little bit of text on this page?

Comment: I would like to know how to do both, I currently probably only need to change a few divs right now, but will probably need to be able to change the language of the whole application at a later stage.

Comment: What we've done so far will set the language for the entire application, so as you navigate from page to page it will get the chosen language. To do it dynamically, at the same time as setting the language you would need to set the CurrentUI culture and then return the divs you want to change during your jQuery post.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I have been looking at rebuilding the divs in my JQuery but do not like this approach, so I am goingn to look at another way of doing this, probably without the client side element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the culture somewhere (cookie/session/whatever) and apply it on every request.

In ASP.Net MVC in the global.asax AquireRequestState seems to be an OK place to put the code to apply the culture.